# I/O brings a machine to its knees

Tags: kernel, io, scheduling

Why, on every Linux I've used, when a program is really I/O bound, it bogs the machine down? It just happened when I (accidentally) tried to make `gcc` compile a (valid!) 50Mb C file. GCC was so I/O intensive it brought the machine to its knees.

Another moment is when `apt-get` or similar are downloading packages, sometimes I can't even access the internet in the meantime, all the requests get timed out.

On Windows, the operations may not be *that* fast, but at least the processes get to share the I/O time between them.

Is this because of design decision? If yes, is there anyway I can change this behavior?

(*please do not take this as a critique of Linux*)

Comment: "(valid!) 50Mb C file"... wow!

Comment: @icyrock.com likely the result of some code generator. E.g., to make a large static table of data.

Comment: @derobert Yeah, I assumed nobody would actually go and type that much into one file, but still - wow!

Comment: A 50MB file shouldn't cause so much I/O, but in your case, compiling a 50MB source file can definitely cause your compiler to use a lot of memory, consuming the entire RAM, which then leads to swap usage, which is then I/O bound

Comment: I have to say a 50M .c seems silly.

Comment: It was accidentally generated when I unknowingly put a big file into Qt's resource system. It then proceeded to make a C file like this:

static const char[..] filename = { 0x30, 0x12, ... ALL of the file's bytes, one by one };

Comment: The question still seems too broad. Are you running in a full disk? Is there something mounted over the network? What tools are you using to see IO stats? Tons of questions. Maybe narrow down the question to a specific case and provide more info.

Comment: **This isn't even a question.**  Processes share I/O access time on linux just like they do on any other modern OS.  You need to *make an effort to analyze your issue* and/or ask a real question (such as, "How can I analyze this issue?").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this question is just too broad to address. We can only really deal with specific issues here. There are any number of reasons as to why this is happening. Often poor performance is just misunderstood by the user.

- Is the system out of RAM?
- does it have  a slow HDD?
- Is the system not setup optimally?

I'm not just blowing your question off, but I've done a fair amount of benchmarking over my career and when you tear a supposed performance issue down to the brass tacks there's always a reason and it's usually obvious once you break the problem down into its discrete parts.

To debug this "problem" further one will have to roll up their sleeves and start digging in by first:

- identifying what the rest of the system is doing during this event.
- Is there ample RAM available?
- Is swap being used?
- Are there other processes competing for the finite set of resources on the system?
- Actually time the "slow" running process and compare the perceived differences in run time
- what resources is my process trying to use? HDD? RAM? How much?

This list can go on forever, but these are the types of things you'll need to diagnose before a cure to the problem can be identified.

Comment: Hm I though more than just performance problems, about scheduling of I/O in general, i'm not asking the reason for "x being slow on y resource" (where y could be disk, network, etc), it's more like "x is not letting any other process use y". But if it's still too broad, thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the process running with a lower nice value than any other process? This would be one reason.

Comment: Ok, I agree it's broad now. And actually, it was really not I/O bound because of reading the file, it was because of swap! GCC tried to use over 6GB (!) of RAM, whereas I have 8GB for the whole system.

Comment: @wingleader - yes computers can be annoying little buggers 8-) It was I/O bound just not for the reasons you thought. The I/O bounding was being caused through the use of swap, which is after all I/O on the disk!!!

Comment: @wingleader - always look at the `Mem:` and `Swap:` lines in `top` too. A well run system should never use swap! Swap is bad, if you see any amount of it being used, scrutinize the hell out of that, b/c you're system is telling you something very important. You don't have enough RAM for what you're asking it to do. On modern systems, dipping into swap is a performance drop nightmare.